# Searching by price in a 2D array?

Tags: c++

I have a program that builds a 2D array of a theater. The user can select a seat by position and the monetary amount is changed to a 0 to indicate that the seat is taken. The other method of choosing a seat selects by price. So the user enters a price, a for loop iterates through the array and finds the first instance of that price and replaces it with a 0, then stops. Or at least that's what I tried to do. In practice, it replaced all of those values with 0. I tried using a while loop to close it out once the condition is met, but that didn't work. Here's my  (relevant) code.

```
while (flag == true)
    {
        cout << "\n";
        cout << "You may select tickets by seat or by price. Enter 1 to select by price, or 2 to select a seat. Enter 3 if you'd like to quit." << endl;
        cin >> userSelection;

        if (userSelection == 1)
        {
            cout << "What price would you like to search for? " << endl;
            cin >> priceSelection;
            while (searchFlag == true)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
                {
                    for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
                    {
                        if (Theater [i][j] == priceSelection)
                        {
                            Theater [i][j] = 0;
                            searchFlag = false;
                        }
                    }
                }

                for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) // This for loop is going to output our array so the user can see pricing.
                {
                    for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
                    {
                        cout << Theater [i][j] << " ";
                    }
                    cout << "\n";
                }
            }

        }
```

I'm not sure what really needs to change so that it'll stop after the first price is found and changed. Also, I don't mind to copy/paste the rest of my code if that's necessary.

Comment: Why is this 2D (1D avoids trouble)?

Comment: Because it has rows and columns of seating. I need to present it in a top-down visual for the user.

Comment: Part of your problem may be that searchFlag is only checked *outside of the for loops*. The for loops will always complete in their entirety before you check the searchFlag again.

Comment: Do you know or learned what functions are?  I would suggest you write a function that just searches the array, finds the row,column of the price that matches, and returns that information (as reference arguments, or as a std::pair or something similar).  Once you get that information returned, you know exactly where to set the array to 0.

Answer (score 1):

Just some advice for the future,

Don't hardcode your loop termination conditions i.e. `(i < 9)`.  Have a current length of the array, or number of seats.  That way you ever add more, this will still work.

Also even though you set search flag to false in your if statement, you will still continue through every for loop.  So you will iterate through every seat, every time.  If the price at the of the current seat never matches the user inputted price, you will go into an infinite loop.  Try changing your inner for loop to

```
for (int j = 0; j < someCurrentLengthOfArray && searchFlag; j++)
```

That way you will check if the price matches and if you head an unspecified end of the array.

As was mentioned in one of the comments, why is this a 2D array?

Answer (score 0):

Your while loop is outside the for loop, so all the replaces finish before you get back to the while loop.  If you use @Dieter Lücking suggestion and just use a 1D array you can do this with one while loop

```
int i =0;
while (searchFlag == true)
{
   // ..check for seats
   if (seatFound)
   {
      searchFlag = false;
   }
   i++;
}
```

For 2D arrays you can still use the while loop method, it will just take two of them.

Answer (score 0):

change your for loops:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 9 && searchFlag; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < 10 && searchFlag; j++)
    {
         if (Theater [i][j] == priceSelection)
         {
              Theater [i][j] = 0;
              searchFlag = false;
         }
     }
 }
```

The way they are now, they'll keep iterating through, until the end, no matter what.  If you do as I showed above, they will break when searchFlag is set to true, and pull back out into the outer while loop, which will also then break.